# How to fix failure of PHP code in windows:exec("rm -rf F:/tmpJob/*")

Tags: php, apache, permissions, windows-xp

It's executed when browsing a PHP file(http://localhost/filename.php) on windows.

The web server is Apache.

I think it should be divided into 2 steps:

1.found user of Apache threads

2.give enough permissions to that user towards "F:/tmpJob/"

I checked httpd.conf and found:

```
User daemon
Group daemon
```

But there is no "daemon" user on windows.
How to find the **real** user of apache threads?

Answer (score 1):

Er... `rm -rf` is not a valid command in Windows. The delete command in Windows/DOS is `del`.

The equivalent of `rm -rf FILEPATH` in Windows is `del /S /Q PATH` to delete recurSively and be Quiet about it (i.e. don't give the "are you sure?" prompt).

Comment: I've installed UnixUtils on windows.I can run that command successfully in a prompt.

Comment: Then I'd suggest starting up the Task Manager (Start->Run, enter `taskmgr` and hit OK) and then make sure you're viewing processes from all users, find the Apache process in the list, and see what user it's listed as running as. If you're running it as a service, it's probably SYSTEM.

Comment: Note that you may need to turn on the User Name column in the process view - go to the View menu and then choose Select Columns.... to enable it.

Comment: Just checked that "SYSTEM" has complete control on that directory,so it's not "SYSTEM"

Comment: All user names:Administrator,LOCAL SERVICE,NETWORK SERVICE,SYSTEM.

Comment: Did you find the apache process in the Task Manager application?

Comment: All the 4 kinds of users have complete control on that directory now,but still failed.

Comment: It's httpd,and is running as System.But when you visit a page,it'll fork a new thread,which is not running as System.And can't see from Task Manager !

Comment: What output do you get back from exec()? Since it returns the resulting output of the command back in an array-of-lines format, you might want to print_r() the result and see if that sheds any light on why it's failing.

Comment: Check your path environment variable, or try using an absolute path to the `rm` program.

Comment: Oh my god,it worked after using absolute path(F:/UnxUtils/usr/local/wbin/rm)!
But I've put the directory of "F:/UnxUtils/usr/local/wbin" into PATH of SYSTEM,why?

Comment: @Amber I think it's worth noting that he was looking to "forcibly, recursively delete" the files in the directory. Not suppress the output of the command, so your Windows flags may be incorrect. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @MarcDiMillo The output suppression is also an effect of `-f` (it won't complain) and has the side effect of not prompting before removal, thus forcibly removing. The flags are correct.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the owner of the current process e.g. with [getmypid()](http://php.net/getmypid) and [the wmi class WIN32_PROCESS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394372%28VS.85%29.aspx)

```
<?php
$pid = getmypid();
$wmi = new COM ('winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}//./root/cimv2');
$result = $wmi->execquery("Select * from Win32_Process Where ProcessID = '$pid'");

foreach($result as $row) {
  $owner = new VARIANT('');
  $domain = new VARIANT('');
  $row->GetOwner($owner, $domain);
  echo ' exe: ', $row->ExecutablePath, ' owner:', $owner, ' domain:', $domain, "\n";
}
```

You should probably also check the output of

```
<pre><?php passthru('set'); ?></pre>
```

esp. the PATH variable. Maybe the UnixUtils are not "in" the PATH of the SYSTEM account.

Comment: I've ensured both Administrator and System has access to UnixUtils in PATH.

Comment: Output of your code is:
exe: F:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.2.11\bin\httpd.exe owner:SYSTEM domain:NT AUTHORITY.

Comment: And SYSTEM has complete control to those directories.

Comment: Oh my god,it worked after using absolute path(F:/UnxUtils/usr/local/wbin/rm)! But I've put the directory of "F:/UnxUtils/usr/local/wbin" into PATH of SYSTEM,why?